# SIU23 block off time

Tags: hl7, mirth, hl7-v2

Where I can found Block start date-time and end date-time in SIU23 message.
(The block time is the time which restrict the appointment creation in that time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the semantics of a HL7 message must be defined by the sending/consuming systems (HL7 mainly defines the syntax of the messages).

You are probably looking for the `TQ1-7` (Start date/time) and `TQ1-8` (End date/time) fields of the SIU message. But you should double check with the documentation of the sending system.

[SIU messages definition](http://www.hl7.eu/refactored/msgSIU_S12.html)